# Spring Boot 1.5.9 - Jaxb2Marshaller

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Trying to learn Spring Boot. Taking existing Spring application and rebuilding it in a new boot project. One of my clasess relies upon a dependency org.springframework -> spring-oxm which is for the Jaxb2Marshaller.

In my Spring Boot project when I add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

When I add the above to my POM it never pulls the jar in so I cannot import the Jaxb2Marshaller. I believe Spring Boot logic is keeping this from being pulled in because of the version. I tried other versions, but no luck. What is the proper way to pull in this spring dependency with the right version?

Comment: BTW: Version 3.2.2 is very old. Use the same version for spring-oxm that is used for the other spring dependencies

Comment: I dont think this is a spring-batch related question.